# Raster to Vector: Displaying classes in Vector Layer - GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, reclassify

I use Maximum Likelihood classification to classify Landsat image into two landuse classes - one of my interest and rest including all others. Inorder to assess the accuracy I export it in vector format using `r.to.vect` with feature type as area. But I find no option to export it in such a way that I can differentiate between two classes. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would it be an option to use `r.reclass` to assign for example 1 to areas of interest and 0 to others. Then use `r.to.vect` with the -v flag.

Answer (score 2):

Doing that, you should have a new vector layer with an attribute containing the values. You then use [v.colors](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.colors.html) to specify the desired color for a given value attribute.

See the exemple at the bottom of the given page to understand how the rules mechanism works.